# I'm using a form_tag to update a single field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an invoicing index page, with a table of invoices to be processed.
So, basically, I need 1 field I'd like to update [for each record that needs to be processed].   I have the following form in one of the table details...

```
 <%= form_tag invoicing_path do %>
                <%= text_field_tag :invoice %>
                <%= submit_tag "Save" %>
              <% end %>

No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"invoicing"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

but I can't seem to figure out how to pass the id into this form?

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think [hidden_field_tag](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field_tag) could help you here. Just add it to your form with right `ID`:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :id, ID %>
```

Comment: ok, but my id is coming from the table i'm looping thru.
            <td> <%= iu.id %> </td>

Comment: Ok, then use `iu.id` instead of `ID` in my answer.

Comment: No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"invoicing"} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: still an issue using iu.id

Comment: Could you update your question and include whole template, not only the form? I guess the form and the table are in the same template, correct?